# How do I prevent a WPF ScrollViewer from resizing when its content is resized?

Tags: .net, wpf, scrollviewer

I have this ScrollViewer, and I don't want it to change size when its content resizes.

Is there a way to prevent ScrollViewer resizing when its content control size changes?

More specifically, in the following code, I don't want the ScrollViewer to become bigger because the DockPanel got bigger. I want the ScrollViewer to stay the same.

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <DockPanel  />
</ScrollViewer>
```

### **EDIT:**

Nevermind I figured it out. For some reason the Window containing the ScrollViewer had SizeToContent set to WidthAndHeight. Changing it to Manual fixed my problem, i.e. the ScrollViewer doesn't resize anymore.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, which will make it easier for future people with the same question to find! (i.e. it'll show that the question **has** been answered.) Cheers.

Comment: I can't post my solution as an answer for now as I must wait 24 hours from the time I initially posted the question.

Comment: Why does djacobson get "great comment" mentions??? The site _disallows_ me from actually answering my question and _specifies_ that as an alternative I can edit my question!

Comment: Your answer to my comment is perfectly valid; I'd forgotten that you can't immediately answer your own question. That said, I meant it as a suggestion, not criticism, and once you are able to post an answer, I encourage you to do so. I'm sure that's all the upvoters were agreeing with. Please don't take the suggestion too hard. :)

Comment: Yeah I'll mark this answered with my own answer when I'm allowed to. I just wanted to make it clear that I would have answered my question if I could have. Rest assured that in the future I'll be making this reality clear in any answer as an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind I figured it out. For some reason the Window containing the ScrollViewer had SizeToContent set to WidthAndHeight. Changing it to Manual fixed my problem, i.e. the ScrollViewer doesn't resize anymore.